# Auto scroll from one id element to another id element in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to code a javascript function within a plugin (Slider Revolution) for Wordpress. Due to where I can enter my custom code, which covers the slider, and not my button, I can't directly add custom code to my button. So I need help with developing a function that scrolls at the click of a button (must be accomplished by using the buttons id) to another part of the same page. The id of the button that should scroll is, "Föredrag", and the id of the place where I want to scroll to is "videor".

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You need to give us something, at least.  This site isn't a *"write my code for me"* service.  Have you actually tried this yourself??  Before you go any further, read **[ask]** and then update the question (if it's still open).

Comment: Yes, sorry for the poorly written question. So, the basic function of scrolling to a specific element I know the code for. The problem is that I can't insert that code directly for the button I want to perform the action, instead, there is a general place in Wordpress where I can add custom code, but that code applies for my whole website. So in some way, I first need to target the button (id=Föredrag) that I want to activate the scrolling, and then add the function to scroll down to the specific element (id = videor).

Comment: So you're asking how to make it do something when a specific button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, but I know the code for the actual scrolling function. But I need to the function to first "select" the button (that will start the scrolling).

Comment: You're very bad at explaining things.  Do you want to know how to click a button from code, or do you want to know how to write code that runs when the user clicks a button?

Comment: As you can read in my first reply, I am using Wordpress, my page builder (slider revolution) gives me the possibility to enter custom code, but not custom code for every element (e.g. the button I want integrate the scroll function in), instead the code applies for the whole website, so I in some way have to say in JavaScript; "When I click this button (id=Föredrag), I want it to scroll down to #videor".

Comment: So you want to know how to write code for a button click event?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 0):

I don't catch your case clearly. But if you are asking for scrolling page to specific element, use `scrollIntoView()` function.

```
var element = document.getElementById("someID");
element .scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for the poorly written question. So, the basic function of scrolling to a specific element I know the code for. The problem is that I can't insert that code directly for the button I want to perform the action, instead, there is a general place in Wordpress where I can add custom code, but that code applies for my whole website. So in some way, I first need to target the button (id=Föredrag) that I want to activate the scrolling, and then add the function to scroll down to the specific element (id = videor). Do you understand the issue?